# What does BREAD stand for while drafting?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-drafting, terminology

I was just reading [What are good strategies for booster drafts?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/4921/27268), but as a new player I'm not familiar with a lot of jargon. The accepted answer mentions that BREAD is important when drafting:

> "BREAD" is key, but there is another technique that helps a lot in most Limited formats:

Could someone explain what is meant by BREAD in this context?

Comment: The answer to this question, is the second voted answer in the linked to question.  Wanted to vote to close, but couldn't find a decent reason.

Comment: @John Mark it as a duplicate for that reason, I think. I think the answer would have been better as an edit on the existing question (see my edit to link the text 'BREAD' in the top answer to the answer you recommended).

This isn't a criticism of this question, which is very good! It's just unfortunate that the top answer on the question linked depended on you knowing that an older answer exists.

Comment: @deworde What I understand from my experience at RPG.SE: "duplicate answers aren't the same as duplicate questions". Especially for the sake of future querents, I think there's a difference about asking strategies or terminology within those strategies.

Comment: @deworde But of course if this community thinks differently, I don't mind having the Q get closed as duplicate of course ;)

Comment: I think it's more that the only possible answer to this question exists on the linked question.

Comment: Doesn't make it bad, though, just makes it so it's better to update the existing answer to better inform users like you in the first place.

Comment: @deworde Yes that edit is very helpful!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's an acronym telling you which cards you should pick. Cards fall in one of five categories, and you should (usually) pick the card from topmost category (B > R > E > A > D) which is still left in the pack.

In a nutshell:

- **B**ombs, powerful cards that win a game if unanswered. These can be something that generate an advantage every turn (e.g. [The Immortal Sun](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bThe%20Immortal%20Sun%5d)), planeswalkers, or simply overly-large creatures for the mana cost (e.g. [Lyra Dawnbringer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLyra%20Dawnbringer%5d)).
- **R**emoval, cards which destroy/exile/damage creatures (said bombs, but of course they can be used earlier in the game as well).
- **E**vasion, creatures with special abilities (e.g. flying) which make them harder to block.
- **A**ggro, smaller creatures which give you early presence on the board and make sure you can play a card almost every turn.
- **D**uds, cards you don't want in your main deck but *might* be useful in the sideboard.

Googling for `magic draft bread` gives some articles which explain everything in detail, including examples for each category in the current expansions.

Comment: Re "bombs" -- planeswalkers are almost always bombs.

Comment: Heh, my last draft was probably before those even existed ...

Comment: I edited "bombs" since not all large creatures aren't necessarily bombs - e.g. Giganotosaurus is barely playable, while the humble Mystic Archaeologist is. Feel free to revert if you don't like the edit.

Comment: @Allure except from the last extension, where some Planewalkers can be uncommon, and not "as good" as the older ones.